# How do I fix the Denoiser's cloudy render glitch?

Tags: rendering, lighting, denoise

I have another problem. I've been trying to create a render of my IES light with the Denoiser,but when I do,a weird cloud/noise effect appears in the render. Could someone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to avoid using denoise and use more samples. Or lower the values for the settings and increase the number of samples.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just used too few samples. This question is retarded.

Comment: It's not a bad question.at all